# Seeing red color against violet

Tags: optics

If you put a red dot and violet dot on a wall and move far away from them, after certain period/distance  you will only be able to see the red light, then my teacher explained why/how this happens , which i forgot

I know the W. L. of red is more than violet, hence speed is also more and frequency is less, but how is all that relevant to visibility?

Comment: Whatever your teacher's answer was you really need to read Land's (he of the Polaroid camera) article on [color vision][1].


  [1]: http://www.millenuvole.org/f/Fotografia/Per-quali-ragioni-vediamo-i-colori/edwin_land_the_retinex_theory_of_color_vision.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Refractive index and frequency of blue light tells us that it is more easily refracted and dispersed in air, respectively.

Red light on other hand has less frequency and hence more wavelength. Dispersion is proportional to $\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$
So, it is less dispersed. Also because of less refractive index, it is less bent in air and moves relatively straight.

Because of two combined effects red light easily reach far to you while blue light is dispersed.

Answer (score -1):

> I know the W. L. of red is more than violet, hence speed is also more and frequency is less, but how is all that relevant to visibility?

This is wrong, the speed of light is always fixed at c, the same for all frequencies (and wavelengths).

I do not know the experiment you describe. The most probable explanation is in the biology of the retina of the eye, and not in physics per se. The retina needs a certain number of [photons](http://study.com/academy/lesson/what-is-a-photon-definition-energy-wavelength.html)  ( the underlying layer of light) to raise the necessary receptors for perception, and it may be , as intensity of light from a spot falls as 1/r^2, the violet receptors need more than the infrared ones to give a signal for perception. It is true that for the same intensity there are less photons  in the violet than in the infrared , because the energy of each photon is h*nu, nu the frequency, so each violet photon carries a larger part of the intensity than each infrared. This means fewer violet  photons reach the retina receptors  than infrared ones. At some distance the violet ones might not be enough to carry the signal to the receptors.